# Weaviate db keeps increasing insize, dues to commitlog.d folder. Can I remove it?

Tags: weaviate

I recently found out that my weaviate db is increasing in size everytime I do batch update (adding items and remove items), although the total number of items remains relatively the same.
The issues seems to lie in commitlog.d folder, where it keeps increasing in size, with many .condensed files.
How do I clean up old logs (that I know is not needed anymore), or reduce the size of the logs.

I tried to remove the commitlog.d folder altogether when restarting weaviate, It works fine, but I'm not sure about the consequences of that.

I also searched for ways to clean up weaviate logs, or about the .condensed files in weaviate docs, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the commit log files as this has the graph operations (edge changes) applied to HNSW.

Weaviate has a [commit log combiner](https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/blob/master/adapters/repos/db/vector/hnsw/commit_log_combiner.go) for HNSW that will merge commit logs together and remove duplicate information reducing the size.

What is the current disk utilization of your cluster and sizes of each commit log? Please feel free to directly contact me (on community Slack) as I'd need more info to debug further.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I moved to other vector db though. Not only because of this issue but also quantization issues. I never could get quantization to work with weaviate, the db always malfunctioning when restored from a backup when quantization is used